# Bootstrap grid system is not working in my Wordpress theme

Tags: theme-development, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a long time Wordpress user but this is the first time I dared to build my own theme (while following a tutorial though). I'm trying to use Bootstrap as the layout tool for the theme, but for some reason I can't get it to work. Here is the work-in-progress:

http://youtubeen.com/

I'm expecting the three divs with class="col-md-4"> to sit next to each other horizontally. Instead they stack on top of each other. Is my Bootstrap not loading properly here or what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really a Wordpress related question, more a html/css question for Stack Overflow.

But i did look at your code, you are using Bootstrap 2.3.

```
*/
 * Bootstrap v2.3.2
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world by @mdo and @fat.
 */
```

You should load the latest version (3.3.6) to use `col-md-4` for your containers.

Comment: Thank you very much! It would have taken forever for me to figure this out!